# Passing values from Spring MVC controller to HTML form to pre-fill certain fields

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I am trying to pre-fill certain text fields in an HTML form with values passed from the controller. Here's the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RECLIAM_FORM_URL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView renderForm(final HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    ReclaimForm form = new ReclaimForm();

    form.setProviderName(request.getParameter("providerName"));
    form.setEmailId(request.getParameter("sellerEmail"));
    form.setServiceAvailed(request.getParameter("serviceName"));
    form.setOrderId(request.getParameter("orderId"));

    mav.setViewName(URLConstant.SERVICE_GUARANTEE_FORM);
    mav.addObject("reclaimForm", form);
    return mav;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="providerName" value="${reclaimForm.providerName}">
```

The problem is, it does not pick-up the value, no matter what. I hav even tried the c:out tag, but it doesn't seem to work. What is it that I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: post the full  html file.